# Logical table design in azure tables

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

In your own views how do you design tables in azure logically? Especially when tables can have one to many relationship with other tables.

Here is the given data:

Given is the `product` table, with `PartitionKey` and `Rowkey`
where `PartitionKey` serves as the `ID` of the `Owner (the owner of the product) plus the category`.

```
i.e: hashedowneridstringtype_Cellphone
```

and `Rowkey` serves as the `unique id of the product.`

```
i.e: S6102DXMA2
```

That is the existing design of azure table, and I have to create the following tables below. And since I have no enough idea on how to reflect it in azure, I had to design it using relational tables:

**Products can have reviews from users.**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Review table

Fields:
    ReviewID    - long
    Title       - string
    Review      - string
    OwnerID     - long
    DatePosted  - Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ProductReview table

Fields:
    ProductID   - long
    ReviewID    - long
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Users can comment on the reviews.**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Comment table

Fields:
    CommentID   - long
    Comment     - string
    OwnerID     - long
    CommentDate - date
    EmailUpdate - bool  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CommentReview table

Fields:
    ReviewID    - long
    CommentID   - long
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Users can rate the review, comment and product.**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rating table

Fields:
    RatingID    - long
    Points      - double
    RatedDate   - date
    OwnerID     - long
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CommentRating table

Fields:
    CommentID   - long
    RatingID    - long
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductRating table

Fields:
    ProductID   - long
    RatingID    - long
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

May be what are the things I should consider when designing table in azure?

Answer (score 2):

When designing for Storage Tables in Azure you should think about the queries that are expected to be run against the Table. Which queries do you need to go really quickly, which ones can you afford to be slower, how often will they be executed, how well do they need to scale, etc.

Assuming a frequent query is to return a time sorted list of reviews for a given product, I would start by structuring your reviews table something like:

```
Review table

PartitionKey: ProductID
RowKey: InvertedDatePosted+ReviewID

Fields:
    ReviewID    - long
    Title       - string
    Review      - string
    DatePosted  - Date
    OwnerID     - long
```

If you are sorting by a rating then you may need the rating in the RowKey, if you are sorting by either rating or date then you may need to have 2 seperate tables for Reviews, one keyed by date and the other keyed by rating.

Given that table joins are relatively slow you should try to minimise how often they occur. One way to achieve this is denormalizing the data, for example, including your review owners name and image url inside each review. This means queries to get a list of reviews will not have to join to get the reviewers details, however updates when the reviewer changes his name will be much much slower.

```
Review table

Fields:
    ReviewID    - long
    Title       - string
    Review      - string
    DatePosted  - Date
    OwnerID     - long
    OwnerName   - string
    OwnerImgUrl - string
```

As an alternative you may want to also consider using a Federated Azure SQL Database, that horizontally scales around ProductID.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the idea. As far as I understood, less quantity of tables is better, but still I have to consider the number of queries that could be possibly run against.